# Vertical vs. lateral malleability of copper plate in fine art etching

Tags: metals

The malleability of copper has, in part, contributed to the viability of copper plate etching in fine art through the ages, by offering the ability to “erase” or flatten inadvertently placed or too deeply bitten canal lines in which printing ink will sit. Often a polished metal, flat-rounded tool is used to smooth the surface, by rubbing it over the copper surface with pressure and a lubricant. Thank you for the answer to my previous question on whether copper’s malleability provides for lateral movement of the substance or whether the rubbing action only has a vertically compressing effect. I learned there is both vertical and lateral plastic deformation at play and that work hardening may occur.
Tinted wax or "ground" is melted onto the copper plate before inscribing lines to prevent all parts of the plate from being bitten. The plate then cools. This process often occurs multiple times. Do these multiple temperature changes at the temperature sufficient to melt wax induce much work hardening?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to a forum which deals with material science, metallurgy or chemistry thereof.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero - given that there is a materials-science tag here on Physics SE, this forum deals with it. Often grudgingly, which is irritating to those of us who work in materials/physics/chemistry...

Comment: Given the stress state of applying force at/to a surface, the plastic deformation will occur with both vertical and lateral components. Two items to consider. (1) Work hardening of copper occurs, limiting the total plastic deformation. (2) Copper sheets are usually rolled, which introduces a particular grain structure and internal stresses that then impact plastic deformation.

Comment: @JonCuster yeah but I think this one is really more about the chemical properties...  Anyways: it takes 5 votes to close.